# PhpMyAdmin hang while Import Export

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using MacOS X Sierra and recently I have upgraded MySQL Server to 5.7.20 via homebrew.

After that I noticed a drastic performance reduction of phpMyAdmin during import and export procedures (even with very small databases: few Kb).

The funny thing is that sometimes when I export a db it works fine and quite fast and, after that, if try to export another db phpMyAdmin hangs for very long time until timeout is reached.

That's not a big issue since I can use Sequel Pro as well as CLI to import/export db but it's anyway really strange as well as annoying behaviour.

I tried nearly everything, including cookies deletion, increasing max-allowed-packet in /etc/my.cnf, services restart and so on...
I tried also different PMA versions including 4.7.5 and previous.
Seems nothing is working.

I was wondering if someone else had the same issue?

Thank you in advance.

====== UPDATE

Ok! Seems the problem is related to a not-well-defined as well as unsolvable bug in "liip" package. 
I do not have time anymore to investigate, make tons of tests and useless analysis.
Especially because, while investigating, I found out several other problems related OpenSSL which affect Drush commands as well.

Just a personal tip: 
If you need to configure AMP environment on you Mac do it with Brew. That's what I did and now it works like a charm.

This how-to made my day:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Answer (score 1):

Try to change PHP's max_execution_time to a higher value in the php_ini...
I had the same issue once and put it up to 300

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Isan, thanks for your kind feedback. Yes, max_execution_time can be a fix when you need to export or import big size db. In my case is a bit different. I investigate a bit and I found out that the problem comes from PHP Version (5.6.31). If I switch to another version of PHP (5.6.19 o 7.1 for example) PMA run without any issue. I noticed similar behaviour with Drupal VBO (5.6.19 OK, 5.6.31 KO). I will investigate the config of that specific PHP version and will come back here with the reason.